# WPF Behaviors no longer working with newest NuGets

Tags: wpf, xaml, behavior, attachedbehaviors

The app used to work fine, but a few weeks ago we updated hundreds of NuGet packages. We recently discovered that any reference to a WPF Behavior gives the following error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Add value to collection of
> type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.BehaviorCollection' threw an
> exception.' Line number '78' and line position '86'.'
>
> Inner Exception ArgumentException: Cannot add instance of type
> 'TextBoxInputBehavior' to a collection of type 'BehaviorCollection'.
> Only items of type 'T' are allowed.

I suspect this is because of a NuGet update, but I don't know which one had caused the error, or which need to be changed. I'm using the latest version for Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf (1.1.31).

I would appreciate advice. Thanks.

Code:

```
         xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:MyCompany.MyProject"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"

            <TextBox Text="...">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Behaviors:TextBoxInputBehavior InputMode="DecimalInput" JustPositiveDecimalInput="False" RangeMin="-1000000.000" RangeMax="1000000.000" />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
```

//...

```
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;
//...
public class TextBoxInputBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
//...
```

Comment: Does it still compile, is the error only in the designer? At least from the provided code there does not seem to be an obvious error. You could try to clean the NuGet package cache. Maybe even clean the temporary VS files (`.vs` folder).

Comment: @Stout: Try to restart Visual Studio and/or delete the `bin` and `object` folders in the project directory.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The problem happens on both my local machine and the installed builds. The release build crashes upon startup and does not run. My debug build throws this XamlParseException at runtime, then crashes also.